# How can we show this integral is convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

> Consider the following integral:
> $$\int_{R^n}p(x)q(x)dx$$
>
> where $p, q\in C_c^{\infty}$.

Comment: The question is weirdly asked. If you write $\int_{\mathbb R^2}\frac{\hat p(\xi)\hat q(\xi)}{|\xi|^2}\,\mathrm d \xi$, it sounds that the integral exist. Therefore, your limit should obviously converges...

Comment: If you write $\int_{\mathbb R}f$, then $f$ is integrable (otherwise it has no sense). Therefore, obviously $$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\int_{(-\varepsilon ,\varepsilon )^c}f=\int_{\mathbb R}f.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\int q = 0$ is the same as saying $\hat q (0) = 0.$ Since $\hat q$ is smooth, the trouble at $0$ disappears. (Use polar coordinates to see this.) Also, $\hat p,\hat q$ vanish to high order at $\infty.$

Comment: You don't need to take a limit. This thing is absolutely integrable. We look at

$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi}|\hat p (re^{it})||\hat q (re^{it})|\,dt \frac{1}{r}\,dr.$$ Use $\hat q (0)=0,$ which implies $|\hat q (re^{it})|=O(r).$

Comment: Your second comment: $\hat q$ is smooth. Third comment: False

Comment: New comments: Yes, but that estimate doesn't tell you about $\hat q(x)|x|^{-2}.$  And yes absolute convergence implies convergence.